# Refresh firebase chat messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, refresh

I'm making an app that has a chat room. I used firebase for the chat, my question is, how can i make the chat refresh when an user send a message and how to show the last message when enter the user enter in the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a ChildEventListener to your message ref in firebase.

Something like:

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
         // Do Whatever you need 
}
```

Now with every added child, you can retrieve the message from dataSnapshot and update your adapter dataset or anything you wish.

For the second question, i believe what you are looking for is `queryLimited(toLast: 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have a concept of "refresh".  It's expected that you register a listener for any data that you're interested in, and that listener will be repeatedly invoked as the data changes.  The listener is always "fresh", as long as it's been added, and you have a network connection.

Consider looking into a [ChildEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) to receive new items at a database location whenever they become available.